# CSS Grid – first two items each as 50% of a container, with a third item on 2nd row that is 100%

Tags: css, shopify, css-grid

e.g. with the box that says "Poster Set" on attached image: [image: screenshot of 3 product options], I need this box to extend the full width of the container. Can this be done with CSS grid? It is one of three list items, injected by liquid, contained within a div with the following CSS:

```
.two-columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the grid is two columns, make the poster element cover a 2-column grid area.

There are several ways to do this:

```
poster-set-element {
   grid-column: 1 / span 2; /* start at grid column line 1 and span across 2 more lines */
}
```

OR

```
poster-set-element {
   grid-column: 1 / 3;  /* start at grid column line 1; end at grid column line 3 */
}
```

OR

```
poster-set-element {
   grid-column: 1 / -1; /* start at grid column line 1 starting at the starting edge;
                           end at grid column line 1 starting at the ending edge;
                           (note: this method works only with explicit grids) */
}
```